# Refreshing Data in a Dropdown List

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, cascade-filtering

I have two dropdown lists. The second dropdown list receives a value from the first one to show data, but after the first selection is made in the first dropdown, the second dropdown's data cannot refresh to give new data from the first dropdown list. I used auto post-back in the first dropdown list, but I don't know what can I write in selecting changes.
 here is my code for first dropdownlist post back:

```
protected void PartNamber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
PartNumber.DataBind(); 
PartNumber.ClearSelection(); 
}
```

but it doesn't work too

Comment: Post your code for how you are filling the second drop down list as well as the indexchangedevent for the drop down list.

Comment: Please provide us with some code so that we can take a look at it.

Comment: Are you doing this with jQuery or with a full postback?

Comment: here is my code for first dropdownlist post back:protected void PartNamber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PartNumber.DataBind();
        PartNumber.ClearSelection();
    }

Answer (score 6):

Now you have to write your second query using the DropDown1.SelectedValue as an input parameter to that query. After getting the desired data, you should databind that data in DropDown2.

Sample:

```
protected void DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var data = GetDropDown2Data(((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue);
   DropDown2.DataSource = data;
   DropDown2.DataBind();
}
```

Doing what I show above, every time DropDown1 changes its selected value, DropDown2 will be updated/refreshed with new data based on DropDown1 selected value.